# Do arraylist needs to be specified as return type in method after modification?

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to know what is the best practice to return 'updated' `ArrayList`?

For example, if I am adding in a new element, it seems that whether if I did or did not specify the return type (see the `addNewA()` and `addNewB()`), the `ArrayList` in my `main()` method will still be 'updated' nonetheless.

Should I or should I not specify the return type?
Currently in my client program, most of the methods, I have specified it as `void` (no return type) and while the overall program still does works as intended, thought I would like to get this clarified and make the necessary changes if necessary.

```
public class MyClient
{
    public static ArrayList<Person> addNewA(ArrayList<Person> myArray)
    {
        Person jack = new Person("jack", 24);
        myArray.add(jack);
        return myArray;
    }

    public static void addNewB(ArrayList<Person> myArray)
    {
        Person ben= new Person("ben", 19);
        myArray.add(ben);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Person> personArray= new ArrayList();
        addNewA(personArray); // will return me an array size of 1
        addNewB(personArray); // will return me an array size of 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this, you *should not* return the list and should make your method `void`.

Different languages have different conventions, but one of Java's is that *methods that operate by modifying their arguments* (or the object they're called on) should not return values. Returning a value implies to someone using your code that a different object is being returned, since otherwise there is no use in returning an object the caller already has<sup>1</sup>. A method that is `void`, on the other hand, couldn't possibly be returning a copied-and-extended list, so it's very clear that it's intended to operate by modifying the list that you give it in the first place.

(By the way, [you should also just use `List<Person>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface), and you should pay attention to the warning you get about using `new ArrayList()` instead of `new ArrayList<>()`.)

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a specific exception to this, called the *fluent builder* pattern, but it's not easily confused with general code like this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is clear and noted on the `List<Person>`

Answer (score 1):

In java (and most high level strict type languages) `Object`s are passed by `reference` and primitives passed by `value`.

When using the `new` keyword you create an object.

While primitives (like `int`, `char`, `double` ect) are passed by value (meaning that a copy of the value of the variable will be sent to the invoked function), Object types are passed by reference, meaning that the actual original object is passed to the function.

To sum up - since you are using object here (`ArrayList`), you don't need a return type since the original object is changing.

Comment: Thank you and noted on the objects and primitive types!